# How to set MasterPage body's color from ContentPage in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

So I've got this dropdownlist and I want to change the whole websites background color using it. 
This is my MasterPage body:

```
<body style="overflow: auto;" runat="server" id="bodyMasterPage">
```

And I'm trying to set the background like this.

```
var body = Master.FindControl("bodyMasterPage");

        if (ddlColor.SelectedValue == "Green")
        {
            body.Attributes.Add("background-color", "Green");
        }
```

But when I try add the Attributes to the body, I get an error saying:
"Control does not contain a definition for 'Attributes'..."

So my question is, how should I go about actually changing the background color of the MasterPage from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling very well exactly what kind of error you are dealing with, Master.FindControl returns an object of type *Control* which doesn't an *Attributes* property. *Control* objects, however, can be casted to a specific type they correspond to. In our case **HtmlGenericControl** can do the job.

You have to include the appropriate namespace first by adding the following line on top of the page:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

And then you can adapt your example with this:

```
var body = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("bodyMasterPage");
body.Attributes["style"] += " background-color: green;";
```

Be careful how you are using the attributes, what you have shown in your code would have created an attribute of type *background-color* with value *Green*, and what you really want is either add a class to the body or directly access the *style* attribute like I did but adding your value to it.

I specifically used the addition assignment operator, in case you have any other styles on the body so you don't overwrite them and just include your change. However if you want to completely rewrite it you can change it around or use your approach with proper attribute name (*style*).